# How to actually use context?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Edit: Solved using hooks

I've been going at this like crazy. I have a problem where I have to use a prop, in one other component. I understand that I should use contexts.

I've followed some tutorials, but for some reason, I cannot apply it to my own code.

```
export const FetchContinent = (props) => {
    console.log(props.continent)

return (
    <div>
        {props.continent}
    </div>
)
};
```

props.continent logs exactly what I want.

I want to use that exact value in this other component, as a prop.

```
const JumbotronPage = (continent) => {

  return (
    <MDBContainer className="test">
      <MDBRow>
        <MDBCol>
          <MDBJumbotron className="text-center">
            <MDBCardTitle className="card-title h4 pb-2">
              <CountryList
                continent={["NA"]} //<-- HERE!!
                displayFields={["countryName"]}
              />
              <CountryList continent={["NA"]} displayFields={["revName"]} />
            </MDBCardTitle>
```

So I want to use "props.continent" like (note that this is in another JS-file and another component):

```
               <CountryList
                continent={[props.continent]} //<-- HERE!!
                displayFields={["countryName"]}
              />
```

I feel like I've turned every stone but I cannot come up with a solution.
I've vacuumed my failed tries to make the code more readable.

Edit:
Updated code:
FetchContinent:

```
export const FetchContext = createContext();

export const FetchContinent = (props) => (
    <FetchContext.Provider value={props}>
        {console.log("Fetch continent: " + props.continent)}
      {props.children}
    </FetchContext.Provider>
  );
```

I'd like to print that value in another file:

```
const JumbotronPage = (props) => {
  console.log("Props.continent: " + props.continent);
  const value = useContext(FetchContext);
  return (
    <FetchContext.Consumer>
      <h1>{value}</h1>
    </FetchContext.Consumer>
  );
};
```

However, Value becomes undefined.

Edit 2:
This is how I use FetchContinent:

```
const Africa = ({}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <VerContinentToolbar before="Memories" continent={["Africa"]} />
      <FetchContinent continent={["Africa"]} />
```

Edit 3:
Full code:
JUMBOTRON (Code I had before I started with contexts):

```
const JumbotronPage = (props) => {

  console.log(<VerContinentToolbar props={props.props} />);
  console.log("fdfds");
  return (
    <MDBContainer className="test">
      <MDBRow>
        <MDBCol>
          <MDBJumbotron className="text-center">
            <MDBCardTitle className="card-title h4 pb-2">
              <CountryList continent="Africa" displayFields={["countryName"]} />
              <CountryList continent="Africa" displayFields={["revName"]} />
              <CountryList
                continent={props.continent}
                displayFields={["countryName"]}
              />
              <CountryList
                continent={props.continent}
                displayFields={["revName"]}
              />
            </MDBCardTitle>

            <MDBCardImage
              src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(70).jpg"
              src="https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX32059289.jpg"
              className="img-fluid"
            />
            <MDBCardBody>
              hej
              <MDBCardTitle className="indigo-text h5 m-4">
                <CountryList continent="Africa" displayFields={["beerPrice"]} />
                <CountryList continent="Africa" displayFields={["foodPrice"]} />
                <CountryList
                  continent="Africa" 
                  continent={props.continent}
                  displayFields={["beerPrice"]}
                />
                <CountryList
                  continent={props.continent}
                  displayFields={["foodPrice"]}
                />
                <CountryList
                  continent={props.continent}
                  displayFields={["hostelPrice"]}
                />
                <CountryList continent="Africa" displayFields={["dest1"]} />
                <CountryList continent="Africa" displayFields={["dest2"]} />
                <CountryList continent="Africa" displayFields={["dest3"]} />
                <CountryList
                  continent={props.continent}
                  displayFields={["dest1"]}
                />
                <CountryList
                  continent={props.continent}
                  displayFields={["dest2"]}
                />
                <CountryList
                  continent={props.continent}
                  displayFields={["dest3"]}
                />
              </MDBCardTitle>
              <MDBCardText>
                <CountryList continent="Africa" displayFields={["review"]} />
```

I want:

```
<CountryList
                  continent={props.continent}
                  displayFields={["dest3"]}
                />
```

props.continent to be passed from:

```
const Africa = ({}) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <VerContinentToolbar before="Memories" continent={["Africa"]} />
      <Breadcrumb continent="Africa" />
```

This component.

Edit 4:
So, if I access my component "Africa":
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IwmhO.jpg
I'd like to load every country from my database with the continent "Africa"

When I click "Africa", I want to see every country currently in the database associated with Africa:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vvnh.jpg

When I click a country, I want to display the information from the database in a jumbotron:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khxrv.jpg

The data I'd like to view:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwhNa.jpg

Problem is,
When I click on a country, I have to set the continent to the corresponding continent. First, I wanted to pass it as a prop, but then I got recommended to use context and now I'm here.

Edit 5:
I'm not really sure if contexts is the way to go. A friend recommended me to try it but could not help me further.

Edit 6: 
Country-list:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import firebase from '../config'
import './Countries.css'



const useCountries = continent => {
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
    console.log("Country list: " + continent)

    useEffect(() => {
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection(continent[0])
            .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                const newCountries = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({

                    id: doc.id,

                    ...doc.data()

                }))
                setCountries(newCountries)

            })
    }, [])

    return countries
}



const CountryList = ({ continent, displayFields = [] }) => {
    const countries = useCountries(continent); // <--- Pass it in here

    return (
        <div className="countries">
            {countries.map(country => (
                <div key={country.id}>

                    <div className="entry">

                        {displayFields.includes("continent") && (
                            <div>Name of continent: {country.continent}</div>

                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("revName") && (
                            <div>{country.revName}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("countryName") && (
                            <div><Link to={"./Jumbotron"}>{country.countryName}</Link></div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("dest1") && (
                            <div>Destination 1: {country.dest1}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("dest2") && (
                            <div>Destination 2: {country.dest2}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("dest3") && (
                            <div>Destination 3: {country.dest3}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("beerPrice") && (
                            <div>Beer price: {country.beerPrice}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("foodPrice") && (
                            <div>Food price: {country.foodPrice}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("hostelPrice") && (
                            <div>Hostel price: {country.hostelPrice}</div>
                        )}
                        {displayFields.includes("review") && <div>Review: {country.review}</div>}
                        {displayFields.includes("imgUrl") && <img src={country.url} alt="no-img" />}

                    </div>
                </div>

            ))}
        </div>
    );
};


export default CountryList
```

Thanks,

Comment: I not sure I follow your code but i will write an explanation answer about context and how you may use it in your case

Comment: I'll try to explain it.

This is a review application, so I have each continent listed. 
I use       <FetchContinent continent={["Africa"]} /> in the Africa component, to pass the value "Africa" to the FetchContinent component.

Then I want to take that value (from FetchContinent) and pass it to a jumbotron. I will use the continent to fetch data from a firebase database.

Comment: do you set a provider per continent ??

Comment: No, I just pass it to the FetchContinent.
Should I? I thought, because I can print the value of the continent in the fetchcontinent, I can set a provider there.

Comment: No i think better to have a single provider for all continents

Comment: Do you mind explain or show how I should do that? I'm a bit lost..

Comment: Added an answer with a demo

Comment: Thanks. I'll go ahead and read through it. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to ask for further explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you read [the docs about context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and some other sources. I will try to cover some missing parts I had while working with context for my first times.

1. A `Context` consists of two parts: A single provider, and consumers. The provider is the part responsible on holding the values, and the consumers will get these values and will be notified with every update.

```
const MyContext = React.createContext(null);

// bellow code is for illustration only
const MyContextProdiver = ({ children }) => <MyContext.Provider value={{ continentsData: [] }}>{children}</MyContext.Provider>;

const MyContextConsumer = () => {
  const contextValue = React.useContext(MyContext);

  return null; // a react element must be returned here
}
```

2. A consumer must be rendered somewhere in the tree in the consumer.

```
<MyContextProvider>
  <MyAppThatSomewhereHasAConsumer />
  // or may be directly <MyContextConsumer /> but the idea of the context is to be used in multiple parts
</MyContextProvider>
```

3. If you have only one consumer, you probably don't need the context and you must locate your state in the right place.
4. While using Context api across several projects, I use a trick that I find a good practice to notify me if I forgot to put the provider in the right place (also to notify my teammates). I create a hook to use my context, ie: `useMyContext()`

```
// this assumes that your context will always start with a truthy value
function useMyContext() {
  const myContextValue = React.useContext(MyContext);
  invariant(myContextValue, 'Have you forgot to put a <MyContext.Provider> somewhere up in the tree ?');
  // or simply put if (!myContextValue) throw new Error('there is no MyContext provider') 
  return myContextValue;
}

// later

const contextValue = useMyContext(); // and you will notified if you are in a tree where there is no provider
```

Projecting these notes into your requirements, I suggest that:

1. Make a `ContinentProvider` that will wrap all consumers and provide them with the countries.
2. The context may hold data for multiple continents and the consumer choose what he needs.
3. The context only hold values, it can be more intelligent and provide a fetchContinentData(continentName) function that will on demand fetch a continent countries if not exists already in cached data
4. You can make a hook that provides directly the continent countries: `useContinentCountries` that uses the `useContinentProvider`

Here is [a codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-tree-r2uvt) that looks like this:

[image: codesandbox example]

Comment: Hm. I'm having trouble understanding how I should go ahead and fetch the correct continent. Should I use the provider in each continent-component? Such as this:
      <ContinentCountriesProvider continent={["Africa"]} />

Comment: No, The example I provided will fetch for all the continents and store it internally once and for all. When I used it, I gave it all the continents.

Comment: Are you talking about lazy loading the continents' countries ?

Comment: I'm not really sure if I follow you. I'm very new to this, sorry! :)

Comment: All I want is to get the prop from the continent sent to a component, so I can use it as a variable to index the correct data from my database.

Comment: Ah sorry, By lazy loading I meant that you will not fetch all supported continents with all countries in the first time, but rather, you will each time change the supported continents and fetch its data

Comment: Exactly. Let me upload some images!

Comment: I've thrown in some images and more edit. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help a newbie out!

Comment: After seeing the images, my codesandbox may still help you in that. the continents prop to provider may fetch from database the required data (`continents={[selectedContinent (Africa)]}`). The provider then fetches data and store it in context, consumers will then grap it from anywhere

Comment: I also advice that you review your components, no component should have continent="Africa" as a prop, but rather it should have a variable.

Comment: I'll look into that once I've managed to solve this. Thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: You are welcome, feel free to ask questions, we ve all been there.

Comment: What bothers me is that initially, I could log the correct continent in my FetchContext. The only thing I wanted to do is to transfer that prop to another component and use it there. It can't be that hard, yet I've been here for 7 hours now. :)

Right now I don't really care about best practices. I just want it to work.

Comment: The context should be a parent of that component that's all. Did you make sure it is the case?

Comment: I'm not really sure. What I did was only:
"<FetchContext.Provider value={props}>
        {console.log("Fetch continent: " + props.continent)}
      {props.children}
    </FetchContext.Provider>"

I think I'll give up for today. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: You are doing the whole props as value for your context (it will contain also the children which are a long-long javascript object). simply do value={props.continent} and make suure that the context provider is a parent of the consumer

Comment: I guess my problem is that I cannot understand who's the parent and who's the child.

Comment: I have this in my Fetch:
"import React, { createContext } from "react";
import { Jumbotron } from "react-bootstrap";

export const FetchContext = createContext();

export const FetchContinent = (props) => (
  <FetchContext.Provider value={props.continent}>
    {console.log("Fetch continent: " + props.continent)}
  </FetchContext.Provider>
);
"

I try to do this in my jumbo:
"return (
    <div>
      <FetchContext.Consumer>
      <CountryList continent={["Africa"]} displayFields={"countryName"}></CountryList>
      </FetchContext.Consumer>

    </div>
  );
};"

Comment: the thing is jumbo should be a child of FetchContinent, directly or deep down in the tree

Comment: Thank you for your time. I managed to figure it out. Wasn't really that hard after all. Who said learning should be painless. :)

Answer (score 0):

React Context needs a Provider of the Data and a Consumer.

[image]

https://de.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider

https://de.reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer

Answer (score 0):

There is library which actually makes it easier to use multiple contexts https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dynamic-context-provider.

Comment: I forgot to add that I managed to solve this but wow, this is great. Thank you a lot!